# Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, hierarchy

I developed with WinDev Mobile , which generates a project I then opened with XCode to compile .
Only in WM sharing functionality on facebook has not yet been developed,  I must to develop in ObjC

I started with the code:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook] ;
    [controllerSLC setInitialText:myMessage];
    [controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myUrl]];
    [controllerSLC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myImage]];

    // NSLog (@"% @", [UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow.rootViewController.)

    [self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];

    controllerSLC.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        NSString *output = nil;
        switch(result) {
            SLComposeViewControllerResultDone box:
                output = @ "Your tweet has-been sent" ;
                status = 2;
                // NSLog (@" SENT ");
                break;
            SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled box:
                output = @"Your tweet has-been canceled ";
                status = 3;
                // NSLog (@" canceled ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [controllerSLC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] ;
    };

}
```

I only got an error :

```
Warning Attempt to present <SLComposeViewController > on <CFenPrincipaleViewController> Whose view is not in the window hierarchy !
```

I added the code :

```
UIViewController *activeController = [UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow.rootViewController. ;
if ([ activeController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    activeController = [(UINavigationController *)activeController visibleViewController] ;
}
[activeController presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

It works on the window home application, I have no error .

But when I call the same function on another window , the error returns ....
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Aff I found just after having posted, just added :

    else if (activeController.modalViewController) {activeController = activeController.modalViewController;}

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue...give this a shot!

First get the root view controller....

```
-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController {
return [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
}
```

Now instead of `activeController = [(UINavigationController *)activeController visibleViewController] ;`

Do this:

```
UIViewController* activeController = [self getRootViewController];
```

Now your last line `[activeController presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];` should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's help me a lot, I got the same issue too when I tried run the SLComposeViewController from not parent view :) thanks a lot,